# How to publish to google play from visual studio

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio, testing, google-play

I have a cross platform Xamarin app that I have already delivered to App Store Connect for internal testing and it works great.  It was not an easy process but now that it is setup properly my testers get an email every time I upload a new version for them to test.

I expected a similarly arduous task to get the Android version up on to Google Play for testing and I was not wrong.  There is a lot of documentation (for instance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=windows) but much seems out-of-date and I kept getting stuck and frustrated that this has to be so complicated.  However, I finally have achieved some success and I wanted to share my procedure and I have a question at the end.

- In VS change from **debug** to **release**
- Right click on Droid project and select **properties** - under **Android
  options/Android package** format select **bundle**
- Right click on Droid project and select **archive** - this will initially
  build a bundle that is not signed so it can’t be uploaded to Google
  Play but we will use it to create a **Signing Identity**.
- Once the archive is done the **Archive Manager** will open.  Select it
  and tap the **Distribute** button.  Select the **Google Play** channel.
- On the **Signing Identity** page use the **+** to create a new **Android
  Keystore**.  This will not be applied to the current bundle so we must
  do the archive again to get it signed.
- Back in the Droid project **properties** select **Android Package Signing**,
  check the checkbox to sign the .APK, although we are actually
  creating a bundle and not the .APK.  Navigate to the Keystore and
  provide the password that you just created.  Also, fill in the Alias
  using the name of the keystore and provide the password again.  I am
  not sure why this necessary. Now we can create another archive as
  before but it will be signed!
- Theoretically one could then use the **Distribute** button of the **Archive
  Manager** to upload the bundle to Google Play, but that requires you to
  have an OAuth client on Google Play.  I could not figure this out (it
  requires an SHA-1 certificate fingerprint that I could not find) and
  fortunately there is another way.
- After logging in to Google Play use the **All apps / Create App** button
  to create the app project that will be used for testing and release.
  There are a lot of hoops to jump through but they do a pretty good
  job of walking you through the whole process.  You won’t be able to
  initiate testing until all the requirements are fulfilled.

There are two notable steps:

- For certain permissions you will need a privacy policy online.  I
  used this site to create mine:
  https://pages.flycricket.io/gammadog/privacy.html
- For certain permissions you will need a YouTube video explaining how
  your app uses these features.  Here is mine:
  https://youtu.be/GVbKg1OS7Lk
- After setting up your Google Play app project (whew!) you can now select it under
  **All apps**.  On the left side there is a **Testing** section.  Select
  **Internal testing** and then Tap the **Create new release** button.
- Back in your VS **Archive Manager** tap the **Open Folder** button to reveal
  your archive (.aab).  You can now drag this to the App bundles upload
  rectangle on the **Google Play app project/Internal Testing/Releases** tab. It will upload the bundle and check its
  requirements.  If you are like me you will have to go and fix things
  in your Google Play project (jump through a few more hoops) before it
  will upload without error.
- Still in your **Google Play app project/Internal Testing** select the **Testers** tab.  Here is where you set up your testers.  Presumably there is a way to send a bulk email to all testers at once but I don't see how to do that.
- However, there is a "**Copy link**" under "**How testers join your test**".  The confusing thing is that initially the "**Copy link**" is not active and there is no indication as to why.  After some time it finally becomes active and you can send this in an email to your testers.

So here is my question:

I have been using an Android tablet for testing this app and it works perfectly when loaded from VS.  However, when I click on the link from my email that takes me to Google Play to install it the install never completes and it just sits there spinning forever.  Has anyone else run into this and come up with a solution?

Comment: One of my Android testers reported back that the install works for him on his recent model phone.  It may have to do with the fact that my Galaxy tablet is quite old and will not update to the latest software.  It runs the app just fine though.

Comment: Really appreciate you posting your steps here. I've been experiencing what seems like out of date documentation, or a mismatch of different approaches, or instructions for a previous version of VS that doesn't match 2022/community's UI. It's like I have a travel guide helping me but at every fork in the road the advice it to take a path that is blocked, isn't even there, or marked with a sign in an alien language. It's maddening.

Comment: The funny thing is that after my app was on Google Play for a few months it was abruptly removed and my 10 year old developer account was canceled.  I had mistakenly used a YouTube link for my website and they claimed I was impersonating YouTube.  All my attempts to explain that it was an innocent mistake fell on deaf ears.  After months of trying to get an account reinstated I finally posted my app on the Samsung Galaxy store.

Comment: Ugh. Not fair and what a hassle! Was your Samsung Galaxy store experience better or still difficult?

Comment: Much better experience with Samsung Galaxy store.  A few times they have discovered problems with certain models and have provided me with screenshots or even a video showing the problem.  This has given me enough information to fix the problem even when I cannot reproduce it with my test devices.  BTW my app is gammaDog if you care to try it out.